# cambiar el body background con input type check

Tags: javascript, html

```
body{
    background-color: #333;
}

label input:checked ~ body{
    background-color: #ffefcd;
}
```

la intención esta en cambiar el fondo de la página cuando el input esté checked

Comment: CSS es cascada, con esto me refiero que un elemento "por debajo" no puede "subir", es decir, tienes un body -> div -> check. Necesitarás de JS para realizar lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Eso no es posible, el operador `~` funciona para seleccionar [elementos hermanos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), pero no al contenedor. En todo caso, habrá que esperar a CSS4 para poder usar `body:has('label input:checked')` que, por ahora, parece [funcionar solo con Safari](https://caniuse.com/css-has). Mientras tanto, tienes que recurrir a Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usarías Javascript

```js
document.getElementById("cambio").addEventListener("change", function() {
      if (document.getElementById("cambio").checked == true) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("style", "color: white;");

      } else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", "background-color: white;");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("style", "color: black;");
      }
    });
```

```html
<input id="cambio" type="checkbox">Cambiar fondo
    <p>Otro texto</p>
```

Que de hecho es es una respuesta que anteriormente habían respondido [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52009644/18310531) en inglés